# Spring Security Custom UserDetailsService with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, spring-security

In my application, I am using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.1, and I am on JBoss AS7 w/ JDK7.

I want to use my database (will be Postgres, but for now it is Hypersonic for simplicity) for storing my user credentials, instead of keeping them in a file or the config file itself.

Since I am using an ORM in Hibernate already, I would like to continue to use it to handle my user data.  I have read that this requires a custom UserDetailsService, but I have been unable to get this to work.

It does not look like my service is registering correctly and Spring of course cannot pick it up...Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Stack trace is as follows

```
08:33:33,354 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA UserTransaction: org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction@f0be919
08:33:33,354 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA TransactionManager: com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerDelegate@36eb5fab
08:33:33,355 INFO  [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Using JTA TransactionSynchronizationRegistry: com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryImple@16d5efb8
08:33:33,395 INFO  [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] (MSC service thread 1-4) Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/static/**'], []
08:33:33,426 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6428975c: defining beans [tagDaoImpl,contentDaoImpl,userAccountDaoImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,entityManagerFactory,entityManager,dataSource,transactionManager,org.springframework.security.config.debug.SecurityDebugBeanFactoryPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#1,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1,daoAuthenticationProvider,authenticationManager,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,springSecurityFilterChain]; root of factory hierarchy
08:33:33,433 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting bean property 'logoutHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter] while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting bean property 'logoutHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#9': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' while setting bean property 'logoutHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:169) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.getUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:99) [spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.cachingUserDetailsService(UserDetailsServiceFactoryBean.java:39) [spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 65 more
```

My relevant configuration and code is as follows:

**Role.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1,max=25)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]*", message = "must contain only letters")
    private String name;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

**UserAccount.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username","email"}))
public class UserAccount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=6,max=25)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9 ]*", message = "must contain only letters, numbers and spaces")
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private boolean active;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="roles",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name="useraccount_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

**UserAccountDao.java**

```
public interface UserAccountDao {
    public UserAccount findById(Long id);
    public UserAccount findByUsername(String username);
    public UserAccount findByEmail(String email);
    public void add(UserAccount userAccount);
    public void modify(UserAccount userAccount);
    public void delete(UserAccount userAccount);
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

            UserAccount userAccount = userDao.findByUsername(username);

            if(userAccount == null) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");
            }

            return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(userAccount);
    }

}
```

**Assembler.java**

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User buildUserFromUserEntity(UserAccount userAccount) {
        String username = userAccount.getUsername();
            String password = userAccount.getPassword();
            boolean enabled = userAccount.isActive();
            boolean accountNonExpired = enabled;
            boolean credentialsNonExpired = enabled;
            boolean accountNonLocked = enabled;

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            for(Role role : userAccount.getRoles()) {
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
            }

            User user = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
            return user;
        }
    }
```

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
...
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userDetailsService` -->  `userDetailsServiceImpl`?

You name it as `@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")`, but you use `"userDetailsService"` in context declaration

Comment: That was a stupid typo...I fixed it to use `userDetailsServiceImpl` in the context declaration, however I am still getting the error: `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: No UserDetailsService registered.`  I tried changing all references to `userDetailsService` and `UserDetailsService` and they are still producing the same errors.

Comment: Makes sure that you correct declarete     <context:component-scan base-package="{your base package name}" />

Comment: Ah, I added a new package for the services and did not add the component-scan, so that fixed by adding the dep through maven...there was an error regarding CGLIB, which was fixed by adding that...I then received some more errors around the `daoAuthenticationProvider` having invalid getters/setters...removing those two beans and just keeping the `authenticationManager` produced no errors.  I will need to test this however.

Comment: Ok, the remaining errors appear to be related to my DAO...I am accepting this error for the `<context:component-scan base-package="xxx"/>` comment, as that was what answered my question...stupid mistake by me. nice catch and thanks for the help!